# Silverstripe dataobject to display in multiple pages

Tags: silverstripe, data-objects

I cant seem to figure out how to use a data object in multiple ways. Right now I can only get it to display in one page.

I want to be able to edit the items of the table in the cms, display a list of items on one page and then one specific item on another page.

Here is how I have structured it so far which allows me to list all the clients in a page and edit them in the CMS. I can not list them on a page other than "clientPage" nor can I see a detailed view page of one client.

```
class Clients extends DataObject {
 public static $db = array(
    //All the table columns
);

 // One-to-one relationship with profile picture
public static $has_one = array(
    'ProfilePicture' => 'Image',
    'ClientPage' => 'ClientPage'
);

// Summary fields

public static $summary_fields = array(
    'ProfilePicture.CMSThumbnail'=>'Picture',
    'FIRST_NAME'=>'First Name',
    'LAST_NAME'=>'Last Name',
    'EMAIL'=>'Email'
);

public function getCMSFields_forPopup() {

    // Profile picture field
    $thumbField = new UploadField('ProfilePicture', 'Profile picture');
    $thumbField->allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');


    // Name, Description and Website fields
    return new FieldList(
        //all the editable fields for the cms popup
    );
}
}
```

The ClientPage

```
class ClientPage extends Page{
    private static $has_many = array(
      'Clients'=>'Client'
    );
    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Client', GridField::create(
            'Client',
            'Client List',
            $this->Clients(),
            GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
        ));

        return $fields;
    }
}

class ClientPage_Controller extends Page_Controller{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

If I try to make a directory page using the same data object it does not work

```
class ClientDirectoryPage extends Page {
    private static $has_many = array(
      'Clients'=>'Client'
    );
    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        return $fields;
    }
}

class ClientDirectoryPage_Controller extends Page_Controller{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you try to implement [Polymorfic has-one relation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/relations/#polymorphic-has-one) incorrectly.

However according to your goal you should have:

1. A `ClientPage` that `has_one` Client (then Client fields are effectively ClientPage fields, as 1-1 relation)
2. A `ClientDirectoryPage` displays a collection of links to ClientPages, and relation can be implemented in several ways.

   a. Using SiteTree hierarchy: put several ClientPages under ClientDirectoryPage, and access the list with `ClientDirectoryPage::Children()`

   b. Get a list of all pages as `ClientPage::get()` in `ClientDirectoryPage_Controller::ClientPages()`

Comment: Please clarify, why would you need a separate Client class?

Comment: What If I only want to create one client page that populates with the link provided. I have a table already full of clients and do not want to create a page for each.. I am trying to figure out how i can use $datObject::get to display a list of all the rows in the table.. CAn you show me that?

Comment: Clients have multiple data fields and are managed within the site by the site admin. They are not users/members...

Comment: Having that a database table contains your Client data, you can manage this table in SS CMS admin (in the backend) in 2 ways: as SiteTree (page) fields, or DataObject fields. You should use `ModelAdmin` for the latest. If you want to display a table of your Clients on some page (in the frontend) you should use a method on the page controller that returns a list of clients, and template part that renders the table.

Comment: I did end up using the ModelAdmin and DataObject so that I could use the data where needed. For some reason it just took a while to click as to how Silverstripe interfaces with data. Thanks for your help. I am going to mark this as answered as your answer would put me in the right direction to doing what I asked to do although I would now go with your ModelAdmin suggestion instead.